# Replace values in a column for all rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column with entries like:

```
column:
156781
234762
780417
```

and would like to have the following:

```
column:
0000156781
0000234762
0000780417
```

For this I use the following query:

```
Select isnull(replicate('0', 10 - len(column)),'') + rtrim(column) as a from table)
```

However, I don't know how to replace the values in the whole column.

I already tried with:

```
UPDATE table
SET column= (
  Select isnull(replicate('0', 10 - len(column)),'') + rtrim(column) as columnfrom table)
```

But I get the following error.

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: Why are you using a subquery at all here?

Comment: Because I do not know how to do it

Comment: Have a look at [Examples: Basic Syntax - Using a simple UPDATE statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/update-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#a-using-a-simple-update-statement).

Comment: `UPDATE table SET column= isnull(replicate('0', 10 - len(column)),'') + rtrim(column) `

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is going to depend on the data type of your column. If it is a text column for example `VARCHAR` then you can modify the value in the table. If it is a number type such as `INT` it is the value and not the characters which is stored.
We can also express this by saying that `"0" + "1" = "01"` whilst `0 + 1 = 1`.
In either case we can format the value in a query.

> ```
> create table numberz(
> val1 int,
> val2 varchar(10));
> insert into numberz values
> (156781,'156781'),
> (234762,'234762'),
> (780417,'780417');
> /* required format 
> 0000156781
> 0000234762
> 0000780417
> */
> select * from numberz;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
>   val1 | val2  
> -----: | :-----
> 156781 | 156781
> 234762 | 234762
> 780417 | 780417
> ```

> ```
> UPDATE numberz 
> SET val1 = isnull(
>   replicate('0', 
>   10 - len(val1)),'') 
>   + rtrim(val1),
> val2 = isnull(
>   replicate('0', 
>   10 - len(val2)),'') 
>   + rtrim(val2);
> GO
> ```

3 rows affected

> 

> ```
> select * from numberz;
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
>   val1 | val2      
> -----: | :---------
> 156781 | 0000156781
> 234762 | 0000234762
> 780417 | 0000780417
> ```

> ```
> select isnull(
>   replicate('0', 
>   10 - len(val1)),'') 
>   + rtrim(val1)
> from numberz
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> | (No column name) |
> | :--------------- |
> | 0000156781       |
> | 0000234762       |
> | 0000780417       |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=c2ee84079d0387d4e3ab979e0a68e759)*

Answer (score 0):

Usually, when we need to show values in specificity format these processes are performed using the `CASE` command or with other functions on the selection field list, mean without updating. In such cases, we can change our format to any format and anytime with changing functions. As dynamic fields.
For example:

```
select id, lpad(id::text, 6, '0') as format_id from test.test_table1
order by id

Result: 

id  format_id
-------------
1   000001
2   000002
3   000003
4   000004
5   000005
```

Maybe you really need an `UPDATE`, so I wrote a sample query for an `UPDATE` command too.

```
update test.test_table1 
set 
  id = lpad(id::text, 6, '0');
```